# How to label and reference the bibliography section

Tags: biblatex, cross-referencing

I want to reference the section of my document containing the bibliography. As the following MWE shows, it is not as straight forward as I would have thought though. `\printbibheading` seems to suppress the use of `\refstepcounter` that is usually done by `\section`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{Indroduction}
The bibliography is in section~\ref{sec:bibliography} and called \nameref{sec:bibliography}.

\printbibheading[heading=bibnumbered]
\label{sec:bibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]
(Using `\printbibliography` instead of `\printbibheading`, I get the same behavior.)

How do I have to label the bibliography heading to be able to reference it?

Comment: `biblatex` doesn't actively try to prevent `\refstepcounter` or anything else in the normal `\section` command from doing its job. But in order to do all its things `biblatex` needs some groups. So we end up with something like `\begingroup \section{References}\endgroup` and then `\label` attaches to the wrong thing because the assignments for that are local (so the info for the References section gets lost at `\engroup`).

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the `\label` into the title of the section, using the `title` option. If you don't want to change the title, you can use `\refname` to get the default.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{Indroduction}
The bibliography is in section~\ref{sec:bibliography} and called \nameref{sec:bibliography}.

\printbibheading[
  heading=bibnumbered,
  title={\refname\label{sec:bibliography}},
]

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]